# Codeblocks can't find Intel C++ compiler (Linux Mint)

Tags: c++, linux, codeblocks, intel-composer

Codeblocks (v13.12) can't find my installation of the Intel C++ compiler.

I have the bundled version of icc that comes with Composer XE, which I believe is the only way to currently get it. When I go into Codeblocks' toolchain settings I see that it is looking for it in "/opt/intel/cc/9.0" which is wrong. When I try to change this to the actual path to my icc ("/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/bin/intel64") it says that it still can't find it.

Has anyone gotten the current icc to work with the current Codeblocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not an expert. I will provide my settings so that hopefully it will work for you:

settings-->compiler debugger-->toolchain executables-->Compiler's installation directory:
/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013/sp1
C: compiler icc

C++ compiler icpc

Linker for dyn icpc

linker for static ar

debugger: idb

settings-->compiler debugger-->search directories
/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174

I have code:blocks 10.05 on ubuntu 12.04. Hopefully this helps/works for you or someone else!